# How to determine if a custom control is in a Toolbar?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, user-controls, styles

i have created a UserControl to make an `ImageButton`:

```
<Button x:Class="myimagebutton"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:imagebutton">

    <Grid x:Name="grdButton">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Image Grid.Column="0"
               x:Name="btnImage"
               HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               VerticalAlignment="Center">
        </Image>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="{Binding Text}"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Margin="2 0 2 0" />
    </Grid>
</Button>
```

now i want to apply the *[default Toolbar Button Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/how-to-style-controls-on-a-toolbar)* to my Button if this Button is in a Toolbar. I have read this article [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/947293/making-the-toolbar-button-style-apply-to-usercontrols-in-the-toolbar) and put this

```
If Me.Style Is Nothing AndAlso TypeOf Me.Parent Is ToolBar Then
   Me.Style = DirectCast(FindResource(ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey), Style)
End If
```

in my Code behind.

After that as a test I put my Button both in a Toolbar and another out of the Toolbar to test it. But the Button always get the default style, not the style I am trying to set.

After debugging i find out that `Me.Parent` is always `Nothing`. So now is my question: how i get the information that my button is in a toolbar or not?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having some difficulty understanding exactly what you are describing but after reading it through a few times I think I understand.

Am I right so far?

If so, you are wondering then why your button has an image

A few pointers about your description that threw me off and is probably the reason why you haven't seen anybody else post an answer for your question thus far.

> i replaced the the UserControl Item with a Button

Essentially what you have done is created new control that likely inherits from Button. You might have started off with a UserControl but in order to replace the root item in XAML you would also have to make sure your type myimagebutton inherits from Button as well. This is just how XAML works and learning how to explain it this way will help people understand what you are doing.

Normally inheriting from Button is not how developers override the visual style of a button in WPF mainly because WPF doesn't support the concept of what is sometimes referred to as [visual inheritance](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/289715/wpf-xaml-visual-inheritance) and also there are other suitable methods that can be used to solve the problem in a different way. Instead inheritance is mainly reserved for when behavioral modifications or additions need to be made to an existing control class. This being said there are ways to simulate visual inheritance through the use of content controls that work similar to content pages and master pages in ASP.NET but I think this is a bit outside of the scope of your example. Also if you are to pursue the inheritance model you will need to make sure that in your code behind that you are setting the correct default style in the static constructor so posting your code behind for your button would help too.

I believe the reason why your example isn't working is because the ToolBar specifically looks at the types of controls irrespective inheritance in order to to apply it's custom toolbar styles. In your case your control is of type myimagebutton and not Button so the style is not set by the ToolBar which normally directly sets the Style property based on the type of the control using the two potential types of calls.

```
element.SetResourceReference(FrameworkElement.StyleProperty, styleKey);
element.DefaultStyleKey = styleKey;
```

BTW, in your case I believe only the second line is performed by the ToolBar control and styleKey at that point is defined as null.

Now instead of inheriting from Button in the first place you would probably be better off just to create a new ControlTemplate or a DataTemplate for your button and assigning into the Template or ContentTemplate property respectively through the use of a style. This way you are still always dealing with a button and the style is what changes the visual properties.

```
<Window x:Class="HeaderedContentControlTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Height="252"
        Width="372">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="Orange" />
        </Style>

        <DataTemplate x:Key="ImageButtonDataTemplate">
            <Grid x:Name="grdButton">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image Grid.Column="0"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center">
                </Image>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                           Text="{Binding}"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           Margin="2 0 2 0"
                           Background="Pink" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

        <Style x:Key="ImageButtonStyle"
               TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="ContentTemplate"
                    Value="{StaticResource ImageButtonDataTemplate}" />
        </Style>

    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="11">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ToolBar>
            <Button Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"
                    Content="Some Text" />
        </ToolBar>

        <Button Grid.Row="1"
                Style="{StaticResource ImageButtonStyle}"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                Content="Some Text" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Using the ContentTemplate allows you to redefine the inner contents of the Button without loosing all of the special button state transitions and other niceties you would normally like to keep.

See [this related post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/bf9ab656-c0c8-40c1-819c-b4782efc7c59/) on MSDN Forums that also explains similar behavior when adding a StackPanel containing buttons to a ToolBar.